# How can I efficiently get the first x% of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame with 1000 rows. If I wish to create a series of only the first 5% (or the first 50 rows) what is the best way to do this in terms of percentages? (I don't want to simply do df.head(50))
I would like the code to able to adapt I wanted to change x to say 20% or 30%.

Comment: `df.head(round(len(df) * percentage / 100))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
your_percenteage = 5 #or 20, 30 etc
df = df.iloc[:round(len(df)/100*your_percentage)]
```

Comment: I wonder what the speed comparison between this & `.head()` is?

Comment: @AaronN.Brock I'm guessing not much, since it is [literally the same thing](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L3968).

Comment: @jdehesa Good link! I was testing it, and indeed is almost the same time

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is calculate the percenteage before you you call `.head()`

Example:

```
percenteage = 20
rows_to_keep = round(percenteage / 100 * len(df))
df = df.head(rows_to_keep)
```